# Relationship between tablespace and database Size in Oracle

Tags: oracle, tablespace

HI I am trying to create a oracle database in RDS after which i need to create tablespace, required users before dumping the data into required schema user. I want to know is there any relationship between Tablesapce size and database size or i need to adjust both accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course there is a relation between tablespace size and database size.  But your question sounds like you are expecting some sort of limiting parameter. There is not.  "Database size" is simply the total size of all of the files that constitute the database.  And "tablespace size" is simply the total size of all of the files that constitute the tablespace.  There is nothing to be "adjusted".

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-on to @EdStevens, the database size would be considered the total size of the files in each tablespace.

If you are concerned about running out of storage in your Oracle database, you can query the available space used with the following query:

```
select b.tablespace_name, tbs_size SizeGB, a.free_space FreeGB from
(select tablespace_name, round(sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024,1) as free_space
from dba_free_space group by tablespace_name UNION
select tablespace_name, round((free_space)/1024/1024/1024,1) as free_space from                                         dba_temp_free_space) a,
(select tablespace_name, sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 as tbs_size
from dba_data_files group by tablespace_name UNION
select tablespace_name, sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 tbs_size
from dba_temp_files group by tablespace_name ) b where a.tablespace_name(+)=b.tablespace_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Amazon RDS to deploy an Oracle Database, please choose very carefully the license you want to use and the deployment mode.

Amazon RDS for Oracle DB Instances can be provisioned with either standard storage or Provisioned IOPS storage. Amazon RDS Provisioned IOPS is a storage option designed to deliver fast, predictable, and consistent I/O performance, and is optimized for I/O-intensive, transactional (OLTP) database workloads. This obviously is more expensive than standard storage, so depending of what you are going to do with the database, I would use one or the other.

Regarding how to calculate how much space you would need, one of the good things of moving to Cloud is that the storage is way cheaper than in traditional on-premise deployments.

Check this for licensing mode on Amazon RDS for Oracle

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Oracle.html#Oracle.Concepts.Licensing